# Flutter: Trigger PageView page change by function doesn't have animation

Tags: flutter

I want to build a pageView widget that support animated page change by button clicks.

Credit to 'The Growing Developer' who posted the youtube video and I just follow most steps shown in the video.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Jsb9si1-Ek

I successfully create a pageView with two actions button to trigger page change, but no animation, wanna know why. Thanks

[image]

Given Code:

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  TestScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  static final routeName = '/test';

  PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: (){
            _pageController.animateToPage(1, duration: Duration(microseconds: 3350), curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
          }, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)),
          IconButton(onPressed: (){
            _pageController.animateToPage(2, duration: Duration(microseconds: 3350), curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
          }, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)),
        ],
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.grey),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- I am using MacBook Air with M1 Chips
- Newly install flutter with version 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I set microseconds: 3350 which is not noticeable, changed to milliseconds: 350, everything work as expected. Sorry for wasting your time.